# Как правильно/корректно повесить событие на кнопку BUTTON, чтобы выводило результат из задачи JS на правильность скобок?

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

**Добрый день!** Получилось сделать задачу на **правильность скобок** вот так, но не получается сделать вывод через событие **addEventListener.** Чтобы при нажатии на **BUTTON** или с помощью **INPUT** выводило результат.

***Я еще новичок. Подскажите пожалуйста! За ранее спасибо!)***

```js
document.querySelector('.btn').addEventListener('click', isValid);

function isValid(a) {

  const brackets = {
    ')': '('
  };

  const stack = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i] === "(") {
      stack.push(a[i]);
    } else if (stack[stack.length - 1] === brackets[a[i]]) {
      stack.pop();
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  let inp = document.querySelector('.inp').value;
  document.querySelector('.out').innerHTML = inp;

  return stack.length ? false : true;


}

console.log(isValid('()'));
console.log(isValid('(()'));
console.log(isValid('()()'));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" class="inp">
  <button class="btn">Push</button>
  <div class="out">Result: </div>

  <script src="/index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: какую именно строку ты хочешь проверять по клику?

Comment: Это тестовое задание.
Я подключил HTML для того чтобы выводить в console, проверяющий человек написал мне - "Раз уж ты подключил HTML - почему бы не выводить эти "скобки" в HTML форму по нажатию кнопки. Так же можете установить цвет шрифта, в зависимости от правильной или неправильной строки".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Напсиал как надо было обрабатывать ввод по нажатию. Ещё ваш алгоритм, елси честно немного сложный был, потому написал более простой вариант в своей функции, может будет полезно:

```js
document.querySelector('.btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const inp = document.querySelector('.inp').value;
  document.querySelector('.result').innerHTML = isValid(inp);
});

document.querySelector('.check').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const inp = document.querySelector('.inp').value;
  document.querySelector('.result').innerHTML = checkBrackets(inp);
});

function isValid(a) {

  const brackets = {
    ')': '('
  };

  const stack = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i] === "(") {
      stack.push(a[i]);
    } else if (stack[stack.length - 1] === brackets[a[i]]) {
      stack.pop();
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return stack.length ? false : true;
};

function checkBrackets(str) {
  let count = 0;

  for (const letter of str) {
    if (letter === '(') ++count;
    else if (letter === ')') {
      --count;
      if (count < 0) return false;
    }

  }

  return count === 0;
};
```

```html
<input type="text" class="inp">
<button class="btn">Push</button>
<button class="check">Check</button>
<div class="out">Result: <span class="result"><span></div>
```